# Enabling GPS programmatically, causes the GPS indicator to flash while the GPS button is disabled

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast

In the app i am developing, I am trying to enable the `GPS` implicitly/programmatically using the below posted code. But the result is strange for me, the below posted code causes the `GPS` indicator to flash which means searching for a signal is an ongoing task, however, when I wipe down the notification bar, i find that the `GPS` button is gray, which means it is not active, but when wipe up the notification bar, the `GPS` indicator flashes. Is the below code intended for something like that? how to implicitly/programmatically enable the `GPS`?

Code:

```
private void setGPSActive() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent activateGPSIntent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
    activateGPSIntent.putExtra("enabled", true);
    sendBroadcast(activateGPSIntent);
}
```

Comment: You cannot enable GPS starting from Android 2.3

Comment: would you please tell me how to know if i am currently using Android 2.3 or not?

Comment: You can check in your code the value of android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

Comment: i tried "Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();" but the app crashes

Comment: I don't know why without seeing the code, use a simple if statement to compare the variable with the constant defined for each Android release you find a lot of example, Google is your friend